# Why is Deferred factory method has return value in the context of F

Tags: scala, functional-programming, referential-transparency, cats-effect

I'm looking at `cats.effect.concurrent.Deferred` and noticed that all ***pure*** factory methods inside its companion object return the `F[Deferred[F, A]]`, not just `Deferred[F, A]` like

```
def apply[F[_], A](implicit F: Concurrent[F]): F[Deferred[F, A]] =
  F.delay(unsafe[F, A])
```

but

```
  /**
    * Like `apply` but returns the newly allocated promise directly instead of wrapping it in `F.delay`.
    * This method is considered unsafe because it is not referentially transparent -- it allocates
    * mutable state.
    */
  def unsafe[F[_]: Concurrent, A]: Deferred[F, A]
```

Why?

The `abstract class` has two methods defined (docs omitted):

```
abstract class Deferred[F[_], A] {
  def get: F[A]
  def complete(a: A): F[Unit]
}
```

So even if we allocate `Deferred` directly it is not clear how the state of `Deferred` can be modified via its public method. All modification are suspended with `F[_]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue isn't whether or not mutation is suspended in `F`, it's whether `Deferred.unsafe` allows you to write code that isn't referentially transparent. Consider the following two programs:

```
import cats.effect.{ContextShift, IO}
import cats.effect.concurrent.Deferred
import cats.implicits._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)

val x = Deferred.unsafe[IO, Int]

val p1 = x.complete(1) *> x.get
val p2 = Deferred.unsafe[IO, Int].complete(1) *> Deferred.unsafe[IO, Int].get
```

These two programs aren't equivalent: `p1` will compute `1` and `p2` will wait forever. The fact that we can construct an example like this shows that `Deferred.unsafe` isn't referentially transparent—we can't freely replace calls to it with references and end up with equivalent programs.

If we try to do the same thing with `Deferred.apply`, we'll find that we can't come up with pairs of non-equivalent programs by replacing references with values. We could try this:

```
val x = Deferred[IO, Int]

val p1 = x.flatMap(_.complete(1)) *> x.flatMap(_.get)
val p2 = Deferred[IO, Int].flatMap(_.complete(1)) *> Deferred[IO, Int].flatMap(_.get)
```

…but that gives us two programs that are equivalent (both hang). Even if we try something like this:

```
val x = Deferred[IO, Int]

val p3 = x.flatMap(x => x.complete(1) *> x.get)
```

…all referential transparency tells us is that we can rewrite that code to the following:

```
val p4 = Deferred[IO, Int].flatMap(x => x.complete(1) *> x.get)
```

…which is equivalent to `p3`, so we've failed to break referential transparency again.

The fact that we can't get a reference to the mutable `Deferred[IO, Int]` outside of the context of `F` when we use `Deferred.apply` is specifically what's protecting us here.

Comment: That way any method creating an instance encapsulating mutable state (even though the mutable state is accessed through methods where mutation is suspended in `F[_]`) cannot be considered referential transparent. Is that correct?